# Method App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::home does not exist. [Laravel 8]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I was trying to register user using the Laravel Auth. First I got error with `App\User` not found then I fix it with `App\Models\User` it works. I don't really know what with Laravel 8 becuase I never had a problem with user registration with previous version. Then I got this problem

> BadMethodCallException
> Method App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::home does not exist.

I don't really know which code to provide since I don't even touch the default code of the Authentication/HomeController.

But I did changed the namespace in RouteProvider

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class,'home']);
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are calling home method from route in home controller. Only index method exist in your home controller. Firt create home method it will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! I definitely miss the index method. Thank you

Comment: Is it your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `web.php` top  you need to import

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
```

then u can use

```php
Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class,'index']);
```

### Or else

```php
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

use this here no need to import

> **Note** -  your error is showing u don't have `home` method in your controller so create `home` method or change the correct `method` by default it is `index`

Comment: thank you! You explained it in the best way! I already have the namespace inside my `web.php` I was missing the `index` in my route.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class,'index']);`